# Making script run across different browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, web-audio-api

So, I am working with Web Audio API in Javascript. And what I currently have looks like this

```
try {
this.processor=this.context.createScriptProcessor(this.blockLength,2,2);
}
catch(f)
{
    this.processor=this.context.createJavaScriptNode(this.blockLength,2,2)
}
```

Basically, if the first one fails, try the other. I don't quite like this structure. And I think this is not how try/catch structure should look like. But it does the job.

Does someone has a better way of doing this? So, that in case both statements fail, I can give an alert() command.

Thanks.

PS. I am new to JS

Comment: To make your HTML5 development easier, you may try [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) and checkout the [audio detection code](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test for the existence of the method before calling it:

```
if(this.context.createScriptProcessor){
  this.processor=this.context.createScriptProcessor(this.blockLength,2,2);
}
else if(this.context.createJavaScriptNode){
  this.processor=this.context.createJavaScriptNode(this.blockLength,2,2);
}
else{
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a JavaScript guru here, but ill give it a shot. Perhaps you can check if your try/catch statement works by using a boolean:

```
var  isProcessed = false;
try {
    isProcessed = true;
    this.processor=this.context.createScriptProcessor(this.blockLength,2,2);
}catch(f){
    isProcessed = true;
    this.processor=this.context.createJavaScriptNode(this.blockLength,2,2)
}

if(isProcessed == false){
    alert("Not processed!");
}
```

Does this work for you?